# Setting arguments in function

Tags: c++, function

My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Angle {
    private:
        int degrees, minutes, seconds;
    public:
        Angle(){} //required in the assignment 
        Angle(int degrees, int minutes, int seconds){
            this->degrees=degrees;
            this->minutes=minutes;
            this->seconds=seconds;
        }

        void set_degrees(int const degrees){
            this->degrees=degrees;
        }
        void set_minutes(int const minutes){
            this->minutes=minutes;
        }
        void set_seconds(int const seconds){
            this->seconds=seconds;
        }

    int getDegrees(){
        return degrees;
    }
    int getMinutes(){
        return minutes;
    }
    int getSeconds(){
        return seconds;
    }

    int to_seconds(){
        return degrees*3600+minutes*60+seconds; 
    }
};

int check(){
    Angle a;
    if (a.getDegrees()<360 && a.getMinutes()<60 && a.getSeconds()<60) return 1;  
    else return 0;
}

int main() {

    Angle a1;
    int deg, min, sec;
    cin >> deg >> min >> sec;

    if (check(deg, min, sec)) {

        a1.set_degrees(deg);
        a1.set_minutes(min);
        a1.set_seconds(sec);
        cout << a1.to_seconds();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to set the arguments in the `check` function so it will work in it's implementation in the main function. I can't change anything in the main function because it's preset by my professor, assuming I can't place it in the `Angle` class. I get a "Too many arguments to function `int check()`" error.

Comment: you defined `check` to take no parameters, but you are trying to call it with 3 parameters - so first you need to change that. Also `Angle a` inside `check` is not the same instance as `Angle a1` in `main`, so that quite likely won't do what you want it to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an example of a function taking an argument if you look at `set_degrees()`. Making `check()` take arguments would look something like this:

```
int check(int degrees, int minutes, int seconds) {
    // (Use these values somehow)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I could swear I tried that a while ago and it didn't work, and now it does... Weird.. Thanks anyway!